# How to use USB to send video data?

Tags: usb-device

I have YUY2 video data that I want to be sent over USB to a computer. I want the computer to recognize the device as a video device so it can be displayed with software like a webcam viewer. I have tried searching multiple times on different sites, but I can't find out how to send a packet or when to send what packets. Most things I have found about USB don't tell me how to do these things on a smaller level. I am going to be using a microcontroller and a USB-C port.

Comment: you can get usb video converters for pretty cheap. i just got an hdmi>usb3 one for $12; now my pi shows up like a webcam; no more monitor switching.

Comment: Implementing the UVC enough just to show that it works will be a man-month of effort if you're good at it, and perhaps many more if you want to actually pass the validation suite.(and you'll have to set yourself up for that - that may mean expensive software!). You have to ask yourself whether implementing UVC is the right way to go. Perhaps you should license a library that implements it for your microcontroller. Since it's likely Arm, there's no problem finding such commercial libraries.

Answer (score 15):

You will have to implement the USB profile for video cameras, [UVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_video_device_class). It's specified pretty intensely by the [USB Special Interest Group UVC documentation archive](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/USB_Video_Class_1_5.zip).

You'll want to start by reading the FAQ document in there, which explains which document specifies what.

Comment: The spec is free? Wow. I used to implement PCI cards and had to buy the spec

Comment: @slebetman nice, isn't it?

Answer (score 8):

As noted in Marcu's answer, you need UVC.  This blog has a series of posts that works through the process of interfacing a camera and then implementing UVC on several different devices, including a microcontroller and a dedicated ASIC:

https://www.circuitvalley.com/2019/12/diy-cypress-fx3-usb3-usb-3-uvc-camera-ov7670.html

The source code and linked technical notes provide a complete, working implementation, so should be a very useful starting point.  In the past I have found the examples to be extremely useful.